# Drawing a circle on a lineshape in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I my winform, there is a lineshape and now i want to draw a circle on abve of the lineshape control, can some have idea about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw a Circle above the Line Shape, I suggest you to draw a line instead of using LineShape,
After drawing your line then draw the Circle.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event on your form, use the [DrawEllipse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method on the e.Graphics object. Something like this:

```
// Create location and size of ellipse.
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int width = 200;
int height = 100;

// Draw ellipse to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: thanks dude, but i think it will draw line on the form but i want to drar it on the lineshap.